# iOS flip tableview and UIView

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, core-animation

So what I want to do is, I want to flip a tableview and reveal a normal UIView under it, and vise versa. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend starting with the default Utility View application and then adding a UITableViewController to the main view.

If you already have a project, then create a new UIViewController for the back and present it modally. For the transition, set the `modalPresentationStyle` of your backside view to [`UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal).

Comment: I have already started my project as empty project and added something to it so I want to do the flip thing from scratch.

Comment: Ok, then you want to use a modal view, with the [`UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:) presentation style.

Comment: Does it matter if my tableview only fills half of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the UITableView and the UIView on the back with the same UIViewController (sounds like this might be your case given that your tableview doesn't fill the entire screen), you can simply do a view transition between the two views using [transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW113) in UIView.

The fromView is your tableview, which should already be part of the view hierarchy. The toView is your UIView to be displayed on the back of the tableview. It should be detached from the view hierarchy (no superview) before calling transitionFromView.